# REstful POST : Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified

Tags: c#, rest, stream

This error gets thrown

```
Bytes to be written to the stream exceed 
the Content-Length bytes size specified.
```

when I run the following code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json);
using (var webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    requestWriter.Write(json);
}
```

I read, that error could occurs when Method was HEAD or GET, but here it's POST.

Any idea what's wrong there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing the UTF-8 BOM first, because `Encoding.UTF8` does that by default. Short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "text";
        var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetByteCount(text));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding))
            {
                writer.Write(text);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(stream.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
EF-BB-BF-74-65-78-74
```

The simplest fix is *either* to add the preamble size to the content length, *or* to use an encoding which doesn't have a BOM:

```
Encoding utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Use that instead of `Encoding.UTF8`, and all should be well.